# reading dynamic xml that is created with php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am creating an xml file dynamiclly with php after I read data from DB.

this is the file:
http://www.gossipbingo.net/gossipApp/cms/xml.php?skin=1

now I want to read that file from another file with this link:
http://www.gossipbingo.net/gossipApp/cms/read-xml.php

my problem is, that with this code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xml.php?skin=1');
```

it doesnt work...

but with this code, when the file is static, it works...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('boo.xml');
```

this is the headers in the xml.php file:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Content-Type:text/xml");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read it using a full URL:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.gossipbingo.net/gossipApp/cms/xml.php?skin=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe in order to send the GET request you need to provide full url to the file..